# Creating a Custom Login Page for SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I have just installed SharePoint 2013 on my system. And at the time of login it shows me login screen like below.
 [image]

**Requirement is-**
I do not want to implement Form Based Authentication. I just want to turn above dialog into a Form where user can login using AD account.

Answer (score 5):

This is the default Integrated Windows Authentication dialog.  You see this dialog on non-IE browsers (or IE browsers if the SharePoint site is not set in the Intranet zone or if the SharePoint site is not allowed to pass through Windows credentials).  To use Windows Authentication, you will have to utilize this login dialog.  If you would like to use a form for authentication, you can utilize forms based authentication as UserSP has suggested.  You can still utilize Windows Authentication as a provider for [Forms based authentication](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/316748), this seems like the route that would best suit your needs.

Comment: Isn't there a way so that we can create form which authenticates a user using AD credentials?

Comment: The hyperlink in my post describes how to create a form that authenticates against AD credentials.

Comment: But how can we modify Global.asax file in a SharePoint Project? Since we only have Application Pages there.

Comment: @JamesGrizzle link is broken.

Answer (score 3):

You have to create a new .aspx page which inherits from Microsoft.SharePoint.IdentityModel.Pages.FormsSignInPage class.

Please check this link :
http://tomaszrabinski.pl/wordpress/2011/06/23/sharepoint-2010-custom-login-page/

http://www.mssharepointtips.com/tip.asp?id=1093&page=1

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaevans/archive/2010/07/09/creating-a-custom-login-page-for-sharepoint-2010.aspx

Comment: These are not what I want. I just want to change the default dialog box into form. And credentials should be used as before.

Comment: First link is dead.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is something with respect to how browser behave(authentication).
Here is stackoverflow [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86105/how-can-i-supress-the-browsers-authentication-dialog), this might give you an insight and some odd approaches

Answer (score 0):

This dialog is part of Browser. When you enabled windows authentication on web application, application will allow to authenticate user with windows credentials through following link:

```
/_windows/default.aspx
```

The physical location of file is:

```
"Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\TEMPLATE\IDENTITYMODEL\WINDOWS\default.aspx"
```

The page inherits from `Microsoft.SharePoint.IdentityModel.Pages.WindowsSignInPage`. You can disassemble the dll "`Microsoft.SharePoint.IdentityModel`" and see how it is processing the request.